# Redirect to another page after newsletter signup

Tags: newsletter

I am attempting to get my clients website to redirect to a new page that I have created, which will happen automatically after they signup to the newsletter.  I have followed the instructions here but have the same issue mentioned at the bottom of the page - with the URL Redirect Method in place, the redirected page loads but it no longer records the subscriber in the admin: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v/viewthread/273119/#t432370

Has anyone else experienced this issue or have advice on the solution?  I am pretty new to Magento, so my knowledge is limited.

Thanks
Michael

Comment: are you want for frontend.

Comment: have you install any custom module for newsletter?

Comment: Hey Mike, feel free to post the relevant codes that helped you to resolve this issue and then please accept it.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same issue, and there is a simple fix. Rather than overwriting controllers, you can pass a hidden field in the form that defines the redirect URL.

```
<input type="hidden" name="referer_url" value="{my URL}">
```

newAction() in **Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController** by default returns to the same page you're on, but _getRefererUrl() in **Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action** has options for overriding that by passing a parameter in the request.

Answer (score 2):

Magento save  newsletter subscription from  `newsletter/manage/save` and `newsletter/subscribe/new` url that means you `need overwrite your controller class` **Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController** and **Mage_Newsletter_ManageController** and after `subscription successfully you need redirect to you custom` page using

```
$this->_redirect('custompgeurl');
```

See how override a controller in magento http://www.amitbera.com/how-to-override-a-controller-in-magento/

**[Edit FULL CODE]:**

**Step1:** `app/code/local/Amit/Customnewsletter/etc/config.xml` and full code for this file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
    <Amit_Customnewsletter>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Amit_Customnewsletter>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <newsletter>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <customnewsletter before="Mage_Newsletter">Amit_Customnewsletter</customnewsletter>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </newsletter>
        </routers>
    </frontend>    

</config>
```

**step2:** `app/code/local/Amit/Customnewsletter/controllers/ManageController.php`

code is

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', "Mage_Newsletter").DS."ManageController.php";
class Amit_Customnewsletter_ManageController extends Mage_Newsletter_ManageController
{
    public function saveAction()
    {
        if (!$this->_validateFormKey()) {
            return $this->_redirect('customer/account/');
        }
        try {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer()
            ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
            ->setIsSubscribed((boolean)$this->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed', false))
            ->save();
            if ((boolean)$this->getRequest()->getParam('is_subscribed', false)) {
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess($this->__('The subscription has been saved.'));
            } else {
                Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addSuccess($this->__('The subscription has been removed.'));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->addError($this->__('An error occurred while saving your subscription.'));
        }
    //need to change here
       // $this->_redirect('customer/account/');
       $this->_redirect('custompageurl');
    }
}
```

**Step3:** `app/code/local/Amit/Customnewsletter/controllers/SubscriberController.php`

code:

```
<?php
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', "Mage_Newsletter").DS."SubscriberController.php";
class Amit_Customnewsletter_SubscriberController extends Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController
{
    public function newAction(){
               if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $this->getRequest()->getPost('email')) {
            $session            = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
            $customerSession    = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
            $email              = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('email');

            try {
                if (!Zend_Validate::is($email, 'EmailAddress')) {
                    Mage::throwException($this->__('Please enter a valid email address.'));
                }

                if (Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::XML_PATH_ALLOW_GUEST_SUBSCRIBE_FLAG) != 1 && 
                    !$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
                    Mage::throwException($this->__('Sorry, but administrator denied subscription for guests. Please <a href="%s">register</a>.', Mage::helper('customer')->getRegisterUrl()));
                }

                $ownerId = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
                        ->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
                        ->loadByEmail($email)
                        ->getId();
                if ($ownerId !== null && $ownerId != $customerSession->getId()) {
                    Mage::throwException($this->__('This email address is already assigned to another user.'));
                }

                $status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($email);
                if ($status == Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE) {
                    $session->addSuccess($this->__('Confirmation request has been sent.'));
                }
                else {
                    $session->addSuccess($this->__('Thank you for your subscription.'));
                }
            }
            catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with the subscription: %s', $e->getMessage()));
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $session->addException($e, $this->__('There was a problem with the subscription.'));
            }
        }
    //need change here 
        //$this->_redirectReferer();
    $this->_redirect('custompgeurl');
    }

    }
```

**Step4:** `app/etc/modules/Amit_Customnewsletter.xml` and code is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Amit_Customnewsletter>
                <active>true</active>
                <codePool>local</codePool>
            </Amit_Customnewsletter>
        </modules>
    </config>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, but you will have to excuse me as I don't understand what you are telling me to do.  My magento experience is very basic.  I have tried modifying the SubscriberController file, but this has not worked (following these instructions: http://subhashecommerce.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/redirect-to-specific-page-after.html )

Upon reading the Magento official forum, they have advised never to update these files and everything should be done via the admin using the URL Rewrite Management menu.  As far as I am aware the site does not have any custom modules installed.

Comment: not good  use core rewrite.http://subhashecommerce.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/redirect-to-specific-page-after.html give good directon but from app\code\local\  folder controller did not.yuo need to follow just change http://subhashecommerce.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/redirect-to-specific-page-after.html

Comment: Sorry, but I am still not understanding your instructions?

Comment: Managed to solve it. Thanks for your help.  These instructions were correct: http://subhashecommerce.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/redirect-to-specific-page-after.html but the issue was in this location instead: /app/code/local/daffodil/advancednewsletter/controllers/subscribercontroller.php

Comment: All the folder and file name should start with upper letter after local folder except etc folder it fikes

Comment: There are two things to be changed: 1. Step 2: folder "Controller" -> "controllers" 2. There is one extra "}" in the Step 3 at end to be removed.